# I cannot fetch data from using this code

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
public function orderView(Request $request){
    $orderByID = $request->id;
    $orderDetailsView = DB::table('order_details')
            ->where('order_id',$orderByID)
            ->get();
    return view('admin.order.vieworder', ['orderDetailsView' => $orderDetailsView]);
}
```

If i return only $orderByID it shows the id. But using this id i cannot fetch data from the database table. it shows empty array.

Comment: most likely that id does not exist in your order_details table, You should dd($orderDetailsView) and hard-code the id you got from the request and see if you have a result. If you do, from then you can see what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you dear @OmisakinOluwatobi. I have figure out the problem and solve it. Your comment give me the clue of problem.

Comment: I am glad you resolved it. I will however advice that you post the solution as an answer so in the future it can help others with similar issue.

Comment: The problem was in my query. The $request->id was not matched with 'order_id'.

Comment: You can add it as a new answer in the answer box instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$orderss = DB::table('order_details')->where('order_id', '=', $orderByID)->get();
```

Comment: @Hasnain_Ahmed  Accept the Answers if Solve your problems